# how to restore data from older version of gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

I was using git lab (9.5.4) and I took backup and reinstalled complete git lab with latest version. I was trying to restore the data from older version of backup but I am getting error as version mismatch and kindly switch to older version
 I went through some of the Git lab doc but I didn't get useful stuff can somebody help me how can I restore the data from older version of git lab backup? Waiting for the reply. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately GitLab doesn't support that option. You would need to mount a Gitlab with the same version as the one you have, recover the backup there and then update THAT Gitlab, that way you'll have an updated database that you can backup and restore on your installation.

My advice would be to use Docker for the old one (https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/)

Comment: not only for the old one, but also the new one! I have restored my 9.2.5 backup in docker and then upgrade it to 11.1.4